# Why can't I import GameScreen when it used to work?

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I've just started working with libgbx. I work with it in a couple of weaks and it worked great. Then all of a sudden it happened something and I hade to restart my computer, and when I started eclipse again, I had an error, and it said

> GameScreen cannot be resolved to a type

And I can't import GameScreen, which worked before. It says that

> No proposals have been found to fixed the unresolved reference  to 'GameScreen', click here to manually configure the build path of project 'MyGame'

And I don't know what I have to do to make it work. I also had 3 maps in my trashcan on my computer which had the names, `Recovered files`, `Recovered files #1` and `Recovered files #3`, but I don't know if it has something to do with the problem.

Comment: Mind if you post a small code snippet that produces the same error?

Comment: It seems that your eclipse-workspace (or at least your Project) is broken somehow.

Comment: I tried to make a new project but i didn't work. Do you know if its possible to fix? @sasankad

Comment: private GameScreen gameScreen;

This is where I get my error. @DennisMeng

Comment: What I meant was a small snippet that allows use to reproduce the error that you're seeing. Just that one line isn't going to help; there could be a number of things wrong.

Comment: Is your .classpath file intact? The jar or folder containing GameScreen?

Answer (score 0):

If you restarted your computer when eclipse was running. Then your workspace wasn't correctly saved (it does that at closing eclipse). Its very probable you created the GameScreen class in that session thus now it isn't saved in the worspace, but it is on disk.

Click every project (core, android, desktop, gtw if you have that one too). And hit F5 (Refresh) on all of them. Do a clean too, just to be sure. That should solve your problem.

Comment: The Refresh command applies to the entire workspace if you don't have any projects or files selected.

Answer (score 0):

If there is some problem with workspace which seems impossible to be found, its good to start fresh.

- Close eclipse
- Delete .metadata folder
- Restart eclipse
- Open workspace in same folder.
- Delete gwt-cache files in gwt projects
- Clean all projects

This should hopefully solve the problem. Good luck.

Comment: I don´t really know where to find these different folders

Comment: It's the same folder in which your projects are stored. (The workspace folder). To check it, go to "File->Switch Workspace->Others" now you should see the path highlighted. (.metadata folder may be hidden)